# "Property" preserving property under $\sigma-$generating classes

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a non-empty set, $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{C}$ be a class of subsets of $\Omega$ such that $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{F}$. If $\Omega_0$ is a subset of 
$\Omega$ then we know that  $\sigma(\mathcal{C}_0)=\mathcal{F}_0$, that is the restriction $\mathcal{C}_0=\mathcal{C}\cap \Omega_0:=\{A\cap \Omega_0:~A\in \mathcal{C}\}$ of class $\mathcal{C}$ on $\Omega_0$ generates 
the restricted $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{F}_0=\mathcal{F}\cap \Omega$ of $\mathcal{F}$ on $\Omega_0$.

My question is if that passes to Properties: to be more specific, let $P$ be a property regarding measurable sets of $\Omega$ (countable, symmetric, etc) and $\mathcal{C}_P,~\mathcal{F}_P$ are the classes of $\mathcal{C},~\mathcal{F}$ that have this property, then I am wondering if $\sigma(\mathcal{C}_P)=\mathcal{F}_P$.  (I am aware that there is no generallity on this, for example works for symmetric property on $\mathcal{B},~\mathcal{P}$ on the reals but not for the property of being open). If that works somehow, then what kind of properties are preserved?

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!